# EF6 CodeFirst inheritance and foreign relation dependent on discriminator value

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first

Currently I am writing an application using code first approach, and I need to create two very similar entities, lets say representing address so I've created:

```
public abstract class BaseEntity
{
    public Guid Id { set; get; }
}

public abstract class Address : BaseEntity
{
    public string Discriminator { set; get; }

    public Guid ObjectId { set; get; }

    public Guid CountryId { set; get; }

    public virtual Country Country { set; get; }

    public string Town { set; get; }

    public string PostalCode { set; get; }

    public string Street { set; get; }

    public string BuildingNumber { get; set; }

    public string FlatNumber { get; set; }

    public AddressType AddressType { get; set; }

    public bool IsDefault { get; set; }
}
```

And then I have two classes which inherits from Address class like so:

```
public class UserAddress : Address
{
    public virtual User User { set; get; }
}

public class ContractorAddress : Address
{
    public virtual Contractor Contractor { set; get; }
}
```

Now I need to make my model builder to map value of `ObjectId` property in abstract class to two different classes (for `UserAddress` it should points to `User.Id` value and User navigation property should use this value, for `ContractorAddress` it should points to `Contractor.Id` value and `Contractor`  navigation property should use this value)
I want to use Table per Hierarchy (TPH) approach.

My question is, how should I describe those relations in model builder?

Comment: And what exactly is your question?

Comment: My question is, how should I discribe those relations in model builder.

Answer (score 0):

Add configuration classes for your mappings. For TPH use:

```
class AddressConfiguration : EntityTypeConfiguration<Address>
{
    public AddressConfiguration()
    {
        Map<UserAddress>(m => m.Requires("AddressType").HasValue("user"));
        Map<ContractorAddress>(m => m.Requires("AddressType").HasValue("contractor"));
    }
}
```

As for the relations:

```
class UserAddressConfiguration : EntityTypeConfiguration<UserAddress>
{
    public UserAddressConfiguration()
    {
        HasRequired(m => m.User).WithMany().HasForeignKey(m => m.ObjectId);
    }
}
class ContractorAddressConfiguration : EntityTypeConfiguration<ContractorAddress>
{
    public ContractorAddressConfiguration()
    {
        HasRequired(m => m.Contractor).WithMany().HasForeignKey(m => m.ObjectId);
    }
}
```

Mapping your other properties should be pretty straight forward. Finally add your configurations to the model builder:

```
modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new AddressConfiguration());
modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new UserAddressConfiguration());
modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new ContractorAddressConfiguration());
```

Note that TPH means your entities are mapped to one table, so you have one column ObjectId referencing 2 different tables. I would recommend you remove ObjectId from your base class, add UserId and ContractorId to the subclasses and map your relations with those.

Comment: Well, thanks but when I try this in my code I am getting an error that says "The foreign key component 'ObjectId' is not a declared property on type 'ContractorAddress'. Verify that it has not been explicitly excluded from the model and that it is a valid primitive property." After googling some time I've found [this thread](http://entityframework.codeplex.com/workitem/1947) and now I wonder if it is possible at all to model such relation in code first. In database first I had no problem to do this.

Comment: Oh, I somehow overlooked the 'abstract' part on your 'Address' class, sry. Anyway, is there a reason you want ObjectId in the parent class? Why don't you simply do the mapping with a 'UserId' and 'ContractorId' on your subclasses?

Comment: Generally it is my 'so called' first time with code first approach and I wanted one generic field to store id of referenced object (type of this referenced object will be sort of determined by value of discriminator). As I understood by adding to subclasses UserId and ContractorId (in TPH) I will have one database table with all fields from my abstract class and nullable UserId and ContractorId fields. Mayby my approach is wrong for code first, but in database first I had no problem with such relations and mappings.

Comment: No it is possible, remove the abstract from your 'Address' class and you should be good to go. The only thing I am saying is that you will end up with one column 'ObjectId' having two FK constraints. I don't know more about the rest of your schema, but imagine your 'Contractors' table has an entry with ID 123, but your 'Users' table does not have this entry. In this case you will not be able to insert a contractor address with ObjectId 123, because this would violate the FK constraint to your 'Users' table.